# Hibernate Entity Manager: Result Set Mapping

Tags: database, hibernate, ibatis, entitymanager, hibernate-entitymanager

I'm new to Hibernate and I am a fan of iBATIS, but my new work environments forces me to use Hibernate. In the current scenario at my workplace, there are many complex select queries that I feel hibernate doesn't handles very well.

So I thought of writing my own  native SQL select queries, with lots and lots of joins and conditions. So far so good.

I'm using the EntityManager to fire the queries and return the result set. The sample code will look like this:

```
String sqlQuery="select COL_1, COL_2 from MY_TABLE_NAME";
Query q=em.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery,);
List resultList=q.getResultList();
```

Please keep in mind this is just a code sample. I would like to have a way so that the result set as in this example (COL_1 and COL_2) can be mapped to my JAVA Class that has two (or more) fields.

Also note that this JAVA Class can not be an Entity that is linked to a table, So I need a way to define any of my JAVA class as a resultClass, the way we do in iBATIS.

Is there any way to do it? SO that the I just define a mapping somewhere for any JAVA class and the result set from query gets mapped to my JAVA Class automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String sqlQuery="select COL_1, COL_2 from MY_TABLE_NAME";
Query q=em.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery,MY_TABLE_NAME.class);
List<MY_TABLE_NAME> resultList=q.getResultList();
```

look variable in IDE debug mode, you will get what you want.